# Cmake error: unsuitable Qt version

Tags: c++, c, qt, cmake

I'm trying to run cmake via cmd (Windows) on a project I downloaded from GitHub, using `cmake`.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
-- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.6.2" from C:/Anaconda2/Library/bin/qmake.exe
CMake Error at 3rdParty/FindMatlab-rwp.cmake:50 (MESSAGE):
  Generator not compatible: MinGW Makefiles
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:427 (find_package)
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? I tried to find info about the Qt mentioned, but I came up with nothing.

Comment: Probably, the project needs newer QT, or older one. In any case, we can only guess. Have you read documentation about building/installing the project?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes I have. Following it exactly as specified. Nothing about QT is mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @arrowd I'm not sure I understand the context. Should I try it regardless of building the project in cmd?

Comment: This sounds like CMake found the Qt binaries that are provided with an installed Anaconda2. Try to Remove Anaconda 2 directory from the path.

Comment: How do I do that? My code sits within the Anaconda directory